# Как удалить знак рубля из input, добавленный ранее через js?

Tags: jquery, input

Имеется JS, который добавляет в input знак рубля после чисел:

Работает хорошо, кроме того, что после удаления введенных чисел, буква ₽ остается.
Подскажите пожалуйста, какой код удалит ₽ и вернет стандартный placeholder?

Спасибо!

```
$('body').on('input', '.sum', function(){

    this.value = this.value
      .replace(/\d $/, '')
      .replace(/\D/g, '')
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1 ')
    + ' ₽';

  });
```

Comment: <input type="text" maxlength="14" id="sum" class="form-control intro-search sum input" placeholder="5 000 000₽" inputmode="decimal" autocomplete="off" required />

Comment: остается, потому что вы делается присвоение этого знака, нет? `+ ' ₽'`

Comment: наверное да, я не фронтендер, не программист, поэтому не могу сказать. Эта добавленная Р не удаляется обычным бекспейсом. Обычно в интернете ищу куски кода, стараюсь адаптировать под решение не больших задач. Просто уверен, что в js можно добавить еще какой то event, что то вроде (blur) или проверяющий кол-во введенных символов в поле. Только как это прописать, учитывая уже тот код, который есть)

Answer (score 0):

Код прекрасно решил задачу

```
$("body").on("input", ".sum", function () {
  let value = this.value
    .replace(/\d $/, "")
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+([^\d]|$))/g, "$1 ");

  if (value) {
    value += " ₽";
  }

  this.value = value;
});
```